# Search form object at run time

Tags: c#, forms

I have too many checkboxes,buttons,labels.... in my C# from, is it possible to `search` and `go to` one of them at run time? As I know in Visual Studio you can use `Properties Windows` and these is a `ComboBox` shows list like this:

```
button1 System.Windows.Forms.Button
button2 System.Windows.Forms.Button
button3 System.Windows.Forms.Button
label1 System.Windows.Forms.Label
label2 System.Windows.Forms.Label
label3 System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

when you choose one of them then the compiler will show where it is, it is great, but I want to do it in run time and search it by its `name` or `text` attribute

Comment: _"when you choose one of them then the compiler will show where it is"_ - what?

Comment: you can use `Button found = Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name.Contains(hereSearchName));` But what do you want to do with it if you have found it ? and what do you mean by **go to one of them** ?

Comment: @MongZhu   `go to them` is like click one of the items in the `ComboBox` in the `Properties Windows`, the compiler will mark the item on the form with dotted line, I just want to find a button and click it,  but there are like hundreds of buttons in my form

Comment: so basically you want to highlight the chosen button. like a navigation helping tool ?=!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think I can do it with your suggestion

Comment: "will mark the item on the form with dotted line" if you manage to mark it with a hand drawn red arrow, that would be awesome. (if you do, please post a screenshot of it here ;) )

Comment: actually, how do you get  the information into your combobox? may be there is a more direct way to access the controls ? Do you have an extra collection? if so then you could may be simply use the selected index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `SelectionIndexChanged` event of your combobox you can extract the name of the control. If you have it you can search for it in the `Controls` property of your `Form`:

```
Control toBeHighlighted = Controls.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name.Contains(hereSearchName));

// Now do what ever you want with it.
```

If the control is too general and you need the precise type you can get it using `OfType<Type>()`

```
Button buttonToBeHighlighted = Controls.OfType<Button>()
                                       .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name.Contains(hereSearchName));
```